# Metamask chrome extension gives error. How do I fix this?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask

I got this error from `metamask`.

[image]

It was working fine couple of hours ago. I have tried reinstalling/ disable and re-enabling again but nothing worked.

Also,
My smart contract is fully functional (Tested in **Remix Browser based IDE**) and no other errors or logs are present anywhere. I also restarted `Ganache` and re-compiled and re-migrated my contracts with no luck.

Here is my solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Voting {
    address mainAddress;
    bytes32[] candidateNames;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint) candidateVotes;
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) candidatesDetails;

    function Voting() public {
        mainAddress = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier isMainAddress {
        if (msg.sender == mainAddress) {
            _;
        }
    }

    function getAllCandidates() public view returns (bytes32[]) {
        return candidateNames;
    }

    function setCandidate(bytes32 newCandidate) isMainAddress public {
        candidateNames.push(newCandidate);
    }

    function setVote(bytes32 candidate) public {
        candidateVotes[candidate] = candidateVotes[candidate] + 1;
    }

    function getVote(bytes32 candidate) public view returns (uint) {
        return candidateVotes[candidate];
    }

    function setDescrption(bytes32 candidateName, bytes32 candidatesDesc) isMainAddress public {
        candidatesDetails[candidateName] = candidatesDesc;
    }

    function getDescription(bytes32 candidateName) public view returns (bytes32){
        return candidatesDetails[candidateName];
    }
}
```

And I am calling these functions like :

```
let votingContractInstance;
    const contract = require('truffle-contract')
    const votingContract = contract(VotingContract)
    votingContract.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        votingContract.deployed().then((instance) => {
            votingContractInstance = instance
            return votingContractInstance.setVote(this.state.candidateName);
        }).then((result) => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                allCandidates: result
            }));
        })
    })
```

All of the calls are made by this way only.

I am using one of the truffle boxes (`REACT box`) and no logs/errors are present in console either.

Comment: The `revert` comes from the smart contract you're calling into. Without seeing the smart contract code and the details of the call you're making, it's impossible to debug further.

Comment: The easiest way to share the rest would be to simply share the JavaScript code where you're making the call/transaction.

Comment: I have updated the question. So, sorry for the inconvenience. Is this enough? @smarx

Comment: Yup, thank you. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `truffle` and thus can't tell what that code is doing (e.g. whether it's deploying a new instance or trying to find an existing one, etc.), but others on this site will probably be able to help from this information.